# Advice in ID getting clicking to the button

Tags: php, mysql, forms, post, send

Please give me some ideas hot to get ID number in my situation.

I have this script in one file. What I need, it is send an id number of user uder which i pressed button `follow`. This ID we can find in `$row['id']` but i Don't know how to send it to another script `lib/follow.php`.

```
<?php
            $users = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM 111212_users");
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($users)){
//                $_SESSION['f_id'] = $row['id'];
                echo "------------------------------------";
                echo "<li>Full name: ".$row['name']."</li><li>Nickname: " .$row['nickname']."</li><li><form action='lib/follow.php' method='get'><input type='submit' name='follow' value='Follow'><form></li>";
            }
            ?>
```

`lib/follow.php` script. I need send id to variable $followed if it have been sent

```
<?php
session_start();
include "connect.php";
if(isset($_GET["follow"])){
    if(isset($_SESSION["f_id"])){
        $followed = $_SESSION["f_id"];
        $follower = $_SESSION['userId'];
        $sql = "INSERT INTO 111212_follow (followed,follower) VALUES ('$followed','$follower')";
        if (!mysql_query($sql)){
            die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
        }
        header('Location: ../main.php');

    }
}

?>
```

Comment: what is the problem you are getting?

Comment: <input type="hidden" name="follow" value="$row['id']">

Comment: If I'am using session, I'm getting wrong ID to $followed. it's equal to $follower ID

Answer (score 0):

you can use anchor tag to get the values

```
 echo "<li><a href="lib/follow.php?id=$row['id']">Full name: ".$row['name']."</a></li>"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
send  using "<form action='lib/follow.php?followed=".$row['id']."' method='get'>

Receive using $followed =  $_GET['followed'];

Else 
Any how ur getting using session

 $followed = $_SESSION["f_id"];

set the id in session

session_start();
// store/set  session data
$_SESSION['f_id']=$row['id'];
```

Comment: how to set id in session? didn't understand